# How you save Read-Only sheets as your own and edit them on D&D Beyond

Tags: dnd-5e, dnd-beyond

When I go to someone else's sheet on D&D Beyond, it says that I can't edit it because it is a "read-only" character. I can't seem to find a way to save this sheet as my own.

[image: read only sheet]

No one seems to know how. Could you help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### There is currently no way to do this without assistance from the character sheet owner or rebuilding the character yourself.

Obviously you could just build the character yourself, but that takes time.

Alternatively, if you know the owner of the character sheet, you could ask them to copy the character and leave it unassigned in a campaign for you to claim. Otherwise, you're stuck taking some time rebuilding the sheet from scratch.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I thought. Thanks a lot though.